# Why the object is not moving between the waypoints when using navmeshagent?

Tags: unity, c#

First thing I baked the scene : Window > AI > Navigation > Bake > Clicked on the Bake button.
The result :

[image: Baked]

Next is to add to the object that should move a script for the waypoints :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Waypoints : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> points;
    public bool waitTimeToMove = false;
    //notice WaitTime is a float now
    public float WaitTime = 10f;
    public bool randomWaitTime;
    float waitMinTime = 1f;
    float waitMaxTime = 10f;
    public bool loop = false;

    private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    private Transform originalPos;
    //two vars for handling timer
    private float timer = 0;
    private float originSpeed;
    private List<GameObject> waypoints = new List<GameObject>();

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).
        agent.autoBraking = false;

        originSpeed = agent.speed;

        if (randomWaitTime == true)
        {
            WaitTime = Random.Range(waitMinTime, waitMaxTime);
        }

        //transforms dont exist without A GameObject and a GameObject doesn't exist without a transform
        //create a new GameObject to hold our position
        GameObject originalPositionObject = new GameObject();
        originalPositionObject.name = "WP";
        originalPositionObject.tag = "OriginalPositionWaypoint";
        originalPositionObject.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Waypoints").transform;
        //set the new gameobjects position equal to where the transform is right now
        originalPositionObject.transform.position = transform.position;
        //add this to the points list instead
        points.Add(originalPositionObject.transform);
    }


    void GotoNextPoint()
    {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Count == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        // Choose the next point in the array as the destination,
        // cycling to the start if necessary.
        destPoint = (destPoint + 1) % points.Count;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (waypoints.Count == 0)
        {
            waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint").ToList();
            foreach (GameObject wp in waypoints)
            {
                points.Add(wp.transform);
            }
        }

        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.
        if (!agent.pathPending && agent.remainingDistance < 1f)
        {
            //if wait to move is true
            if (waitTimeToMove)
            {
                //if timer is less than 10
                if (timer < WaitTime)
                {
                    //add Time.deltaTime each time we hit this point
                    timer += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                //no longer waiting because timer is greater than 10
                else
                {

                    waitTimeToMove = false;

                    //anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
                }
            }
            //if we hit here waitToMove is false, so go ahead as usual
            else
            {
                if (loop == false && destPoint == points.Count - 1)
                {
                    //anim.SetBool("Idle", true);
                    agent.speed = 0;
                }

                if (loop == true || destPoint != points.Count - 1)
                {
                    agent.speed = originSpeed;
                    // Not working if setting back to loop = true in the inspector
                    // After it was not loop and agent in last waypoint
                    // When setting to loop = true it's not continue to check why
                    // Should continue the loop if loop true !
                    // Loop = true is not working when game is running only on Start

                    GotoNextPoint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also added a NavMeshAgent component to the object that should move :

[image: NavMeshAfent]

but the object is not moving. No errors or exceptions the object just not moving between the waypoints.

Comment: It looks like this object is buried deep in the hierarchy of an animated character, in among the finger bones. Do you observe any different results if you lift it out to the root level on its own?

Comment: @DMGregory You right I already have a parent for that problem in the screenshot you can see it I called it Navi Parent and once I moved the Waypoints component and the Nav Mesh Agent component to that object it's moving.  Now I see another problem. It moved fine between waypoints but at some place the object was stuck in a mountain without the possible to move through or climb over to the other side. So the object started to move backward and forth nonstop like unkown what to do.  What should I do in that case ? Isn't the nav mesh agent should know to move around or climing mountains ?

Comment: It sounds like you have a new question. You can post your answer to this one, then create a new Question post about the next topic. Or you can edit this question to ask about your new issue instead.